# Reputation without upvote

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, voting, score

[HypGeomUpvote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410396/motivations-for-hyperbolic-geometry/1410520#1410520)

How did it add to reputation without upvoting in answer?

Comment: "Reputation without upvote". Sounds like a line from a T.S. Eliot poem.

Comment: What the poem's title?

Comment: The Hollow Men, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer you linked has one upvote and one downvote, which gives a total score zero, but positive net reputation gain. (Since upvote is +10 and downvote is -2.)

Any user with [at least 1k reputation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) can see breakdown of the score into upvotes/downvotes simply by clicking on the score.

You can see this also on the [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info) of the post https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1410520/timeline, where you can additionally find out that this answer received an upvote today and a downvote on May 8.

Your total reputation breakdown is available here: https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: Yeah thanks Martin, I rarely see the timeline chronology.

Comment: Well, probably the fastest way to see the number of upvotes and downvotes i clicking on score - timeline, reputation breakdown, reputation tab, etc. are useful if you want more information.